# I can't use Listview.builder inside SinglechildScrollview

Tags: flutter, listview, builder, singlechildscrollview

```
body: (
          SafeArea(
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 ListView.builder(
                   itemBuilder: (context,index)
                   {
                     return(
                         Container(
                           height: 100,
                           width: 100,
                           color: Colors.red,
                         )
                     );
                   },
                   itemCount: 20,
                 ),
               ],
             )
           ),
          )
      ),
```

I want to make it scrollable list of items basically trying to copy the ui of instagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `ListView.builder` already includes scrolling you don't need to use the `SingleChildScrollView`, do you have any specific requirements to use both of them? If so you could try wrapping the `ListView` into a `SizedBox` and specify a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set `shrinkWrap: true` inside `ListView`